# How to keep URL query parameters when following a link?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code of **login.html**:

```
<ul>
  <li class="introduction">
    <a href="introduction.html">
      <span class="icon"></span>
      Introduction
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="login active">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="login"></span>
      Login
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

An external link will first take to the current page (login) with some **query parameters I want to keep**. If the user clicks the first link `introduction`, the introduction.html will be loaded. However, all the query parameter of the previous page (login) are lost.

Is there anyway I can do this page load while keeping the query parameters? Either using HTML or Javascript.

Many thanks.

Comment: Modifying the link URL to include the parameters is an option

Comment: Query parameters? You mean the GET values you are parsing with that page?

Answer (score 30):

The part of the URL you're interested into is called [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location).

You may link to another page with the same parameters using

```
<a onclick="window.location='someotherpage'+window.location.search;">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 10):

Automatically append your current params to any links you deem worthy via a `rel=""` attribute on `<a>` tags (using jQuery):

```html
<a href="introduction.html" rel="keep-params">Link</a>
```

```js
// all <a> tags containing a certain rel=""
$("a[rel~='keep-params']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var params = window.location.search,
        dest = $(this).attr('href') + params;

    // in my experience, a short timeout has helped overcome browser bugs
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = dest;
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: What is with the set timeout? What bugs have you encountered?

Comment: I've experienced issues where the browser processes the location change without other function statements being completed and resulting in weird behaviour. This is going back a few years now, but I like to keep it just to be safe. This is the same method Google Analytics uses for external links.

Answer (score 5):

Modify all `a` tags client side to include query params

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].forEach(e=>{
//add window url params to to the href's params
  const url = new URL(e.href)
  for (let [k,v] of new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).entries()){
    url.searchParams.set(k,v)
  }
  e.href = url.toString();
})
```

Note: if you add a new `a` tag programatically after this script ran, it will not update it, so it won't work for SPA's for example

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it 
a) doesn't mess up URLs that already have query parameters, and
b) doesn't require modifying each <a> tag